# calculating vertex normal in opengl c++ ( gouraud shading)

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

I just started learning C++ and OpenGL. I'm trying to calculate vertex normal in OpenGL.

I know there is a function `glNormal3f`. However, I am not allowed to use that function. Rather I have to calculate vertex normal with codes and an obj file. So what I am trying to do is, I first calculate surface normals and then calculate vertex normal.

I declared operators such as `+,-,*` , and other functions like `innerproduct, crossproduct`.

```
void calcul_color(){
VECTOR kd;
VECTOR ks;
kd=VECTOR(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
ks=VECTOR(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
double inner =  kd.InnerProduct(ks);

int i, j;
for(i=0;i<cube.vertex.size();i++)
{
    VECTOR n = cube.vertex_normal[i];
    VECTOR l = VECTOR(100,100,0) - cube.vertex[i];
    VECTOR v = VECTOR(0,0,1) - cube.vertex[i];
    float xl = n.InnerProduct(l)/n.Magnitude();
    VECTOR x = (n * (1.0/ n.Magnitude())) * xl;
    VECTOR r = x - (l-x);

    VECTOR color = kd * (n.InnerProduct(l)) + ks * pow((v.InnerProduct(r)),10);
    cube.vertex_color[i] = color;
}




for(i=0;i<cube.face.size();i++)
    {
        FACE cur_face = cube.face[i];

glColor3f(cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id1].x,cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id1].y,cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id1].z);
            glVertex3f(cube.vertex[cur_face.id1].x,cube.vertex[cur_face.id1].y,cube.vertex[cur_face.id1].z);
            glColor3f(cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id2].x,cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id2].y,cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id2].z);
            glVertex3f(cube.vertex[cur_face.id2].x,cube.vertex[cur_face.id2].y,cube.vertex[cur_face.id2].z);
            glColor3f(cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id3].x,cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id3].y,cube.vertex_color[cur_face.id3].z);
            glVertex3f(cube.vertex[cur_face.id3].x,cube.vertex[cur_face.id3].y,cube.vertex[cur_face.id3].z);
    }
```

Comment: Have you used glNormal3f to check your results?

Comment: i used glcolor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0) to see if it works and it works fine!

Comment: when i put glcolor3f, i see a teapot made up of little colored triangles!

Comment: If your code works perfectly, then what is your question?

Comment: i can't use glnormal3f i have to calculate normal and vertex normal and put the results in glcolor3f

Comment: not glcolor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0.0) for example, rather glcolor3f(resultsx,resultsy,resultsz) something like this

Comment: Start with something simple, then add complexity slowly. You have written `innerproduct` and `crossproduct`; *test them.* When they work perfectly, you can write other functions and *test them.* When they all work perfectly you can run them on the teapot.

Comment: @Biswajit_86: [you just got a mention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294206/user-being-encouraged-to-insert-inappropriate-formatting?cb=1#comment193243_294206) on Meta! (In other news, please don't use code formatting for languages and technology names - sentence case is fine, or all-caps for acryonyms. Applying code formatting here triggers people's OCD, including mine).

Comment: @halfer, thanks for the heads up. reviewing the meta post. Is there a communication mechanism within SO that i cna use to communicate with you outside of comments

Comment: @Biswajit: there is no private messaging, no. I have a public email address on my blog About page, if you wish to get in touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to compute vertex normals is this:

- Initialize every vertex normal to (0,0,0)
- For every face compute face normal fn, normalize it
- For every vertex of the face add fn to the vertex normal
- After that loop normalize every vertex normal

This loop is a nice O(n). One thing to pay attention to here is that if vertices are shared, the normals will smooth out like on a sphere. If vertices are not shared, you get hard faces like you want on a cube. Duplicating such vertices should be done before.

If your question was on how to go from normal to color, that is dependent on your lighting equation! The easiest one is to do: `color = dot(normal,globallightdir)*globallightcolor`
Another way would be `color = texturecubemap(normal)`. But there are endless possibilities!

Comment: yes exactly! i have to go from normal to color -_-. not even allowed to use lighting functions as well! for initializing every vertex normal to 0,0,0 do you mean normalizing? like unit vector?

Comment: @chloe: The loop is for computing vertex normals on the mesh. The trick is to init as literally 0,0,0. Then straight up add in the face normals, then normalize to average them. But that was not your question! Going from normal to color is called lighting. And there are a zillion ways to do that! I wrote about two very simple ones.